# Drupal 7 automatically adds strong tags

Tags: drupal-7

Drupal automatically adds strong tags around my html. I want to delete it

```
<strong>
  <em>
  </em>
</strong>
```

Comment: Where exactly these are in your page? Paste more html.

Comment: www.hpu2.edu.vn/khoalichsu/, please click body and view source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page there are unclosed `<strong><em>` tags:

```
...
Ngọc Thạch, với đề t&agrave;i: <strong><em>&ldquo;Hoạt động thăm d&...
---
```

This is in the lowest right block in the central column. After that, every subsequent text is rendered as bold italic. This is probably related to the way you are truncating the text in the block. Drupal has a `text_summay()` function that handles text truncation that you may try and use. You can also check [this discussion on Drupal's site](https://drupal.org/node/221257) for further details.